# JQuery Text Input Autocompletion For a Tree of Values

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

Everybody

I have a text input which content should be limited to a set of values. Those values are of the form dependency1,dependency2,dependency3, so they form a tree. I would like to offer a smart auto-completion for this field that knows about this structure. For example, the structure is something like this:

```
Engineering
  Electric
    Communication
    Power
  Electronic
    Computation
    Control
Economy
  Economy
  Accounting
Education
  Basic
  Language
    English
    French
  Sciences
    Math
    Physics
```

So once the user has typed enough letters, the first dependency should be completed and it should be ready to auto-complete the next dependency. If some options appears in a popup, they should be limited to the dependency we're on and not all the tree.

Do you know any jQuery (or otherwise) library that offers something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a fiddle from another search on grouping of values.  Worked on it a bit more - I think this is going to work well - I only have one level of grouping, but more could be added I think:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kieveli/c1wgjLfv/3/

HTML:

```
<label for="search">Search: </label>
<input id="search">
```

CSS:

```
    .ui-autocomplete-category {
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: .2em .4em;
        margin: .8em 0 .2em;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }   
    .ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
        padding: 0em 1.5em;
        width: 220px;
        clear: both;
    }
    .Products {
        width: 220px;
    }
    .People {
        width: 220px;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
 $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {

     _create: function() {
        this._super();
        this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
    },

     _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {

         var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";

         $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            var li;
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category " + item.category + "'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }

            li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );

            if ( item.category ) {
                li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
            }
        });
    },

     _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li>" )
        .addClass(item.category)
        .attr( "data-value", item.value )
        .append( $( "<a>" ).text( item.label ) )
        .appendTo( ul );
    }
});

$(function() {
    var data = [
        { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
        { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
        { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
        { label: "bannttop C13", category: "Products" },
        { label: "cannttop C13", category: "Products" },
        { label: "dannttop C13", category: "Products" },
        { label: "eannttop C13", category: "Products" },
        { label: "fannttop C13", category: "Products" },
        { label: "gannttop C13", category: "Products" },
        { label: "hannttop C13", category: "Products" },
        { label: "iannttop C13", category: "Products" },
        { label: "jannttop C13", category: "Products" },
        { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
        { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
        { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" },
        { label: "bandreas johnson", category: "People" },
        { label: "candreas johnson", category: "People" },
        { label: "dandreas johnson", category: "People" },
        { label: "eandreas johnson", category: "People" },
        { label: "fandreas johnson", category: "People" },
        { label: "gandreas johnson", category: "People" },
    ];

    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: data
    });
});
```

Comment: What if variable depth and dynamic categories?

Answer (score -3):

Not exactly the type of question that should be asked on SO, but there is a plugin called jQuery-UI, which is dependant on jQuery, that has an autocomplete plugin built in. Take a look at:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/